# Animating Size Change in Isotope

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-isotope

Has anyone found a way to animate the change in size between minmised and maximised Isotope items?

I have found one solution but it only works if all items are the same width/height: http://metafizzy.co/blog/isotope-animating-item-sizes/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this Isotope sandbox](http://www.hopfnordin.se/demo.html) demonstrates what you're after?